# Is it possible to use one machine kinda as a proxy for a RDP connection?

Tags: remote-desktop

So normally I have my work laptop from where I can start a VPN connection to be able to connect to my work PC. **What I do** is to start a RDP connection from my private PC to my work laptop, and on the work laptop I connect to my work PC via VPN.

**What I want to do** is to skip the step with connecting to my work laptop and just connect straight from my private PC to my work PC using the work laptop as some kind of proxy (for the VPN connection)?

Some more info: all machines use Windows 10 and I have (at least) local admin permissions on all of the machines.

---

Found a very similar question (which doesn't provide a proper answer): [Workaround for nested RDP?](https://superuser.com/questions/71256)

Comment: There are likely several ways, but what OS is your work laptop running, do you have administrator rights on it, and what VPN software is being used?

Comment: Right, forgot to add these information to my question. Windows 10 + (at least) local admin on all machines.